# Generate random integer in range multiple of another integer in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, random, integer

I'm struggling to finish the utility method to generate a number in a range of 2 integers which is also a multiplier of another integer.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getIntegerInRangeMultipleOf(100, 1000, 444);
}
```

Should yield either **444** or **888**. Nothing else.

I've came up with this solution:

```
public static int getIntegerInRangeMultipleOf(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive, int multiplier) {
    return Math.toIntExact(Math.round((Math.random() * (maxInclusive - minInclusive) + minInclusive) / multiplier) * multiplier);
}
```

But for the example above sometimes it yields **0** (zero) in addition to **444** and **888**.

Please suggest how to fix the function.

Comment: You built a step function over a range of 900, rounding the results to the nearest 444.  Should `444` and `888` be equally likely, or is there some sort of weighting because the range is larger?

Comment: No weighting implied at all. Both 444 and 888 should be equally likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify the math a bit. Let's create a minimum multiplier and a maximum multiplier.

If `minInclusive` is less than (or equal to) `multiplier`, then we know that we can set `minMultiplier` to `1`. Otherwise, it's equal to the next multiple of `multiplier` that is greater than `minInclusive` divided by `multiplier`.

`maxInclusive` always has to be greater than (or equal to) `multiplier`, so we can set `maxMultiplier` to `maxInclusive / multiplier`.

Then, we just multiply `multiplier` by a random number between `minMultiplier` and `maxMultiplier`, inclusive on both ends:

```
public static int getIntegerInRangeMultipleOf(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive, int multiplier) {
    int minMultiplier = minInclusive <= multiplier ? 1 : (int) Math.ceil((double) minInclusive / multiplier);
    int maxMultiplier = maxInclusive / multiplier;
    return multiplier * ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minMultiplier, maxMultiplier + 1);
}
```

I've tested this with many different ranges of positive numbers and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks. Although I've found 2 issues: 1) It doesn't respect negative numbers: `getIntegerInRangeMultipleOf(-500, 500, 500)` won't yield **-500** as a valid value; 2) It throws an exception if `maxInclusive` is less than `multiplier` and if `multiplier` is **0** (zero). I'm personally fine with both issues, just maybe to make the answer complete you can enhance it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It returns `0` when `Math.random()` returns `0.0`. Can be simply found with following test

```
public static int getIntegerInRangeMultipleOf(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive, int multiplier) {
        double v =0.0 * (maxInclusive - minInclusive) + minInclusive;
        System.out.println("v = " + v);
        return Math.toIntExact(Math.round(v / multiplier) * multiplier);
    }

@Test
public void test () {
    int t =  getIntegerInRangeMultipleOf(100, 1000, 444);
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we add a contiditon to select the addition to the `Math.random() * (maxInclusive - minInclusive)` , we can eliminate the the 0 case.

```
public static int getIntegerInRangeMultipleOf(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive, int multiplier) {
    return Math.toIntExact(Math.round((Math.random() * (maxInclusive - minInclusive) + ( minInclusive < multiplier ? multiplier : minInclusive) ) / multiplier) * multiplier);
}
```

Comment: The example in the question yields **1332** with this code :(

Answer (score 0):

dont know how to take out the cast `(int)` but seems to work

```
public static int getIntegerInRangeMultipleOf(int minInclusive,
                                              int maxInclusive,
                                              int multiplier) {
    double random =
            ((Math.random()*(1d - 0.1) + 0.1) * (maxInclusive - minInclusive) + minInclusive) / multiplier;
    if(random < 1) {
        return multiplier;
    } else {
        return (int) Math.floor(random) * multiplier;
    }
}
```